# How would Google react to a modal dialog that pops up after the user performs an action?

Tags: seo, google, modal

Recently I noticed on website https://www.cleancss.com/css-minify/ that a opens a modal-dialog for sharing the page after the user performs the "minify" action.  They use a cookie so it only runs once.

How does Google view and rank this type of trick?

[image]

Comment: Google calls out popups as harming user experience [here](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2016/08/helping-users-easily-access-content-on.html): "Showing a popup that covers the main content, either immediately after the user navigates to a page from the search results, or while they are looking through the page."

Comment: For the record, if a site did this to me, they would get an immediate bounce.

Comment: but website have high score in search google :(

Comment: Even if Googlebot detects DHTML popups that happen on page load, it probably doesn't automatically detect ones that happen after an action.  Google may update to penalize sites like this sometime in the future.   In the meantime, harming usability is never good for search rankings.   If this causes users to go back to the search results and find another site to use instead, rankings will get worse.